# Python string removal by comparing multiple list

Tags: python, list

Currently, I have 3 list, each with around 20 elements inside:

1. a source list with text scrapped off of a website, the format looks like this:

area addressbuildingname

**ex. 'midtown parkst100stockton'**

2. second list contains the name of the various areas

**ex. 'midtown'**

3. third list contains the name of the building

**ex. 'stockton'**

Is there a way to compare these lists and remove the area and building name from the first list so I can gather the address and add it to a 4th list

ex. 'parkst100'

Thanks

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say we have 3 lists:

```
a = ['midtown parkst100stockton', 'uptown square200lenton']
b = ['midtown', 'uptown']
c = ['stockton', 'qwerty']
```

You might use below code:

```
d = []
for i,j,k in zip(a,b,c):
    if i.startswith(j) and i.endswith(k):
        d.append(i.lstrip(j).rstrip(k))
```

To get only *middle* values in case string from `a` list starts with appropriate string from `b` list and ends with string from `c` list

Comment: thanks worked great, never thought of using lstrip and rstrip :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
address = ['midtown parkst100stockton']
area = ['midtown']
building = ['stockton']
mylst = map(lambda each:each.strip(area[0]), address)[0].strip(building[0])
print mylst
```

> OUTPUT : parkst100